# Custom field and params with enters

Tags: add-on-development, custom-fields, fieldtype, development

Currently working on a custom fieldtype, but facing a little nasty problem;

Is it possible to parse any custom field with params the following way (with enters):

```
{gmaps_field_extension 
param1=""
param2=""
param3=""
}
```

When i try this, the output is a plain string: `{gmaps_field_extension param1=""param2=""param3=""}` instead of the generated data.

When i using it like this:

```
{gmaps_field_extension param1=""param2=""param3=""}
```

It works!

I have a feeling that EE is not understanding the enters in the tag.

Is there some trick to let this work with enters?

Comment: Just added this as a bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19434

Comment: The best way to test would be to download and install another custom field type to see if it's possible with that one. It *should* be. If it works then take a look at their code to see how they handle character returns.

Comment: I tested with the native file field, and got the same output as i mention before. I tested with a single tag, not a tag pair.
Why you think it should work, do you got an example?

Comment: EL confirmed this as a bug.